# How's current status of my radish

Tags: vegetables, root-vegetables, radishes

I'm fresh at growing radish, I used Captain Jack's Deadbug Brew and Shake 'N Feed Vegetable Plant Food.

I found part of the radish is above the soil, is it ok? Do I need to cut some leaves? How can I ensure radish is good to harvest?

Thanks a lot

[image: radish]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal for the top of the root to be poking out of the ground.

Don't remove any leaves, because the leaves are what make plants grow!

The best way to grow radish is to sow a few seeds at regular intervals (every one or two weeks) and make sure they get plenty of water so they grow fast.

Harvest them when they are still small. Big radishes are hard and woody. They should be ready to harvest about 4 weeks after sowing the seed.